# What are the different 'content_type' for Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

Where can I find a list of all the different `content_type` category that Active Storage has? I am trying to change an icon based on the file type.

For example:
In the [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects), there is `application/pdf`. I have also seen that there is `image/png`, `video`, `audio` or `text`. What interests me is the part before the file extension (therefore `image` or `application`). In which category would a Word or Powerpoint document be for example? How many `content_type` category there are?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content type is the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of the uploaded document. Unless you excluded certain types it could be basically anything because a MIME type should have a certain structure but at least the suffix depends on the application.

Some [common media types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Common_examples) are:

- `application/javascript`
- `application/json`
- `application/msword` (.doc)
- `application/pdf`
- `application/vnd.api+json`
- `application/vnd.ms-excel` (.xls)
- `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint` (.ppt)
- `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` (.odt)
- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` (.pptx)
- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` (.xlsx)
- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`(.docx)
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `application/xml`
- `application/zip`
- `audio/mpeg`
- `image/gif`
- `image/jpeg`
- `image/png`
- `multipart/form-data`
- `text/csv`
- `text/html`
- `text/plain`
- `text/xml`

Comment: Thank you! Seeing from the list you posted, there aren't a lot of "categories" beside application, image, audio, video & text I suppose.

Comment: That is correct. But the application category is very broad from zip files to docs and excel sheets to executeables. That makes it hard to match them to suitable icons.

Answer (score 1):

Rails maintains the Marcel library to do any content-type stuff. The canonical list of every content-type available in Rails is here:

https://github.com/rails/marcel/blob/main/lib/marcel/tables.rb